# Stop PostgreSQL from spliting value(s) in multiple lines?

Tags: postgresql, base64, encode, psql

I'm converting a binary data (bytea) data type to string using `encode(foo::bytea, 'base64')` but the output is being split in multiple lines:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 req_id       | 132675
 b_string     | d4IF4jCCBd4GCSqGSIb3DQEHAqCCBc8wggXLAgEDMQ0wCwYJBAIBMIGYBgZngQgBAQGg+
              | gY0EgYowgYcCAQAwCwYJYIZIAQAwCwYJYIZIAWUDBAIHUwUdH0JybzpY2evf+v9Xg86b+
              | HSGTGYBIb/QwJQIBAgQg1M6/cJ+S39XY1lm43oenxJNLrYcc3hVw7fgwJQIBDgQgIAil+
              | 1JnYbdS0p4pK07kMkb/dbMcxryx6mqbLTzx+YJ6gggQbMI2gAwIBAgIESS7vwTAKBggq+
              | LUxRjUXbTgfGwUKOFwemsc4KXbsLZ13MkbNfAQ==
```

How can get a single string instead?

**UPDATE: based on the solution by @LaurenzAlbe**

Just for the completeness, this is what I end up doing the gave me the result I wanted:

```
translate(encode(foo::bytea, 'base64'), E'\n', '')
```

Comment: hummm.... if you mean `\pset columns xxx` I already tried that but not working....

Comment: nope, it's not - I'm using a 24" display in full-screen mode. It actually doesn't split the string if I don't convert the `bytea` to string.

Comment: TRANSLATE worked! This was causing us issues when we tried passing the encoded string as a URL parameter and the newline was being URL encoded, breaking the original encoding.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`psql` doesn't split your string in multiple lines.

It's the string that contains new-line characters (ASCII 10), and `psql` displays them accurately. The `+` at the end of every line is `psql`'s way of telling you that the value is continued in the next line.

You can use the unaligned mode (`psql` option `-A`) to get rid of the `+`, but the output format is less attractive then.

You can get rid of the newlines in a string with

```
SELECT translate(..., E'\n', '');
```

`decode` will be able to handle such a string.

Comment: Why would `encode(foo::bytea, 'base64')` include new lines in the value?

Comment: That's common with base64. PostgreSQL imposes a limit of 76 characters per line, probably to comply with MIME.

Comment: okay, so what do I now? My actual output is a comma seperatd CSV and its puting those multiple lines within a double-quote, which is breaking the rest of processing. Any solution to fix that?

Comment: @MacUsers: what about using hex encoding? `encode(foo::bytea, 'hex')`

Comment: @MacUsers But that's perfectly valid CSV. Maybe you should get a better CSV parser.

Comment: it's maybe a valid CSV but the existing script expects one line each for a record set, which is not the case anymore. My concern is not with the CSV but with the 'output' by psql itself. it's a quite a lot od things to changed to accept that 'non-standrad'   comma seperated file. Hence my quest...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, unfortunately cannot do anything else - it has to be the `base64` for the target system. But surprisingly it doesn't split the hex output into multiple lines.

Comment: See my extended answer - you can use `translate` to get rid of the newlines.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, excellent!!! That's exactly what I was looking for. Now my XML generator happy again. Thanks a lot!!