# PSQL - encrypt_iv return multiple line encoded text

Tags: postgresql, encryption, aes, public-key-encryption, caesar-cipher

I am facing a issue to load a csv resulting froma query that encryts a text.

This is the query I run:

```
select
  id,
  encode(encrypt_iv(raw_address::bytea, '<aes_key>', '<iv>', 'aes-cbc/pad:pkcs'), 'base64') raw_address
from some_table;
```

But I got a multiline text as result for `raw_address` column. So I tried:

```
select
  id,
  encode(encrypt_iv(replace(raw_address, chr(92), chr(47))::bytea, '<aes_key>', '<iv>', 'aes-cbc/pad:pkcs'), 'base64') raw_address
from some_table;
```

This because I just wanted to make this `\` into this `/` (to avoid `\n`)

This is the result example:

[image]

But got the same result. Then I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53712316) and realize that `+` char was present, so I tried:

```
select
  id,
  replace(encode(encrypt_iv(replace(raw_address, chr(92), chr(47))::bytea, '<aes_key>', '<iv>', 'aes-cbc/pad:pkcs'), 'base64'), chr(10), '')
from, some_table;
```

Then I got one line:

[image]

But I don't know if I am modifing the original value, I can not decrypt the value. I tried:

```
select encode(decrypt_iv('55WHZ7tyGAlQxTIM0fPfY5tOKpbYzwdXCsemIgYV5TRG+h45IW1nU/zCqZbkIeiXQ3OXZSlHo0RPgq5wcgJ0xQ==', '<aes_key>', '<iv>', 'aes-cbc/pad:pkcs'), 'base64') ;
```

But I got:

```
ERROR:  decrypt_iv error: Data not a multiple of block size
```

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me what your goal is, but why are you replacing some chars in the bytea to be encoded? And why don't decode the base64 string first and pass it to decrypt_iv? Not the encode_iv is splitting the result, encode( base64) does, as stated in the docs.

Comment: @Steeeve I replace chars in the bytea to be encoded because I thought the problem was there. But then I realized that the _newline_ char is in the string resulting from `encode` function.